# Cannot create instance of javafx.scene.chart.BarChart with given set of properties: []

Tags: java, javafx

I want to display a bar chart in JavaFX by marking it in a fxml file. I perform all actions with the chart in the drawChart function, when starting the program the error "Cannot create instance of javafx.scene.chart.BarChart with given set of properties: []" is displayed.
fxml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.event.ActionEvent?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<GridPane hgap="15" vgap="15" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
    <ComboBox fx:id="fromCurrency" onAction="#changeFromCurrencyCombo" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
    <TextField fx:id="fromCurrencyText" onTextChange="#changeFromCurrencyText" GridPane.rowIndex="4" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
    <Label fx:id="fromCurrencyLabel" GridPane.rowIndex="5" GridPane.columnIndex="2"></Label>
    <Button fx:id="swapButton" text="↔" GridPane.rowIndex="6" GridPane.columnIndex="2" onAction="#swapButtonClicked"></Button>
    <ComboBox fx:id="toCurrency" onAction="#changeToCurrencyCombo" GridPane.rowIndex="7" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/>
    <Label fx:id="toCurrencyText"  GridPane.rowIndex="8" GridPane.columnIndex="2"/><!--onTextChange="#changeToCurrencyText"-->
    <Label fx:id="toCurrencyLabel" GridPane.rowIndex="9" GridPane.columnIndex="2"></Label>
    <BarChart fx:id="chart" GridPane.rowIndex="10" GridPane.columnIndex="2"></BarChart>
</GridPane>
```

part of the file HelloController.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class HelloController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    public ComboBox fromCurrency;
    public ComboBox toCurrency;
    @FXML
    private Label fromCurrencyLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label toCurrencyLabel;
    @FXML
    private TextField fromCurrencyText;
    @FXML
    private Label toCurrencyText;
    @FXML
    public String currentFromCurrency = ""; //текущая валюта, из которой переводим
    @FXML
    public String currentToCurrency = ""; //текущая валюта, в которую переводим
    @FXML
    private ObservableList<String> items;
    @FXML
    private Button swapButton;
    @FXML
    private List<String> currencies;
    @FXML
    CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    @FXML
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    @FXML
    private BarChart<String,Number> chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    private boolean canChange = true;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Рубль", "Доллар", "Евро", "Злотый");
        fromCurrency.setItems(items);
        fromCurrency.setValue(items.get(0));
        currentFromCurrency = items.get(0);
        toCurrency.setItems(items);
        toCurrency.setValue(items.get(1));
        currentToCurrency = items.get(1);
        HelloParser par = new HelloParser();
        par.connect();
        currencies = par.getData();
        par.checkDate();
        drawChart();
    }

public void drawChart() {
        chart.setTitle("Country Summary");
        xAxis.setLabel("Country");
        yAxis.setLabel("Value");

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("2003");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Austria", 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Brazil", 20148.82));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("France", 10000));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Italy", 35407.15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("USA", 12000));

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("2004");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Austria", 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Brazil", 41941.19));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("France", 45263.37));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Italy", 117320.16));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("USA", 14845.27));

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("2005");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Austria", 45000.65));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Brazil", 44835.76));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("France", 18722.18));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Italy", 17557.31));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("USA", 92633.68));
        chart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);
    }
```

I tried outputting it in the main file, but I don't know how to add it to the scene created using fxml. Direct me where to look, I looked on the official website, but the diagram there is not created through an fxml file

Comment: A `BarChart` cannot be created without specifying the axes. You need to define these axes in the FXML file. Also, never explicitly assign an `@FXML`-annotated field.

Comment: Please tell me how to define axes in fxml? IntelliJ Idea tells me to write @FXML.

Comment: I tried to do this in fxml: <BarChart fx:id="chart" GridPane.rowIndex="10" GridPane.columnIndex="2" xAxis="xAxis" yAxis="yAxis"></BarChart>

but now this error: Cannot create instance of javafx.scene.chart.BarChart with given set of properties: [yAxis, xAxis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the axes of the `BarChart`:

```xml
<BarChart fx:id="chart" GridPane.rowIndex="10" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
  <xAxis>
    <CategoryAxis fx:id="xAxix">
      <categories>
          <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Austria"/>
            <String fx:value="Brazil"/>
            <String fx:value="France"/>
            <String fx:value="Italy"/>
            <String fx:value="USA"/>
          </FXCollections>
      </categories>
    </CategoryAxis>
  </xAxis>
  <yAxis>
    <NumberAxis fx:id="yAxix"/>
  </yAxis>
</BarChart>
```

And make sure you have the needed imports:

```xml
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
```

Note you can specify the categories of the `CategoryAxis` in code (i.e., in the controller) if you prefer.

A few other points:

- **Never** explicitly assign an `@FXML`-annotated field. For example, this:

  ```java
  @FXML
  private BarChart<String,Number> chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
  ```

  Should just be:

  ```java
  @FXML
  private BarChart<String, Number> chart;
  ```
- All `@FXML`-annotated fields should be `private` unless you have a (rare) *good* reason otherwise. Note any non-public field you want injected by the `FXMLLoader` must be annotated with `@FXML`.
- **Only** fields you want to be injected by the `FXMLLoader` should be annotated with `@FXML`. For example, `items` does not appear to be defined in the FXML file, so there's no reason for that field to be annotated with `@FXML`.
- [Do not use raw types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/6395627).

  - You have two raw `ComboBox` fields.
  - All your `XYChart.Series` are raw.
  - All your `XYChart.Data` are raw.

  Parameterize all of those.